# How to hot reload styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

After changing styled component webpack shown as below; how can I hot reload styled component?

> [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload
>   needed) This is usually because the modules which have changed (and
>   their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves.

UPDATE:
I use styled-components 1.1.2

Comment: This has already been answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385034/warning-prop-classname-did-not-match-in-next-js-site-with-styled-components/65862300#65862300. Look the answer from  JulioMalves.

Answer (score 0):

I am using webpack devserver to achieve this.In your package.json update this

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

install the dependency using npm install webpack-dev-server

Comment: I'm also use this command but not working; make sure that you use styled-components: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? If is below 1.0.8, update the styled components.

This is a [issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/97) that is fixed after 1.0.8. Before that it throw the same error as what you have stated.

Comment: I use version 1.1.2.