# Warning: Prop `className` did not match in Next.JS site with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I've searched Stack Overflow for similar questions but the answers either refer to old versions or aren't relevant to my situation.

I get the above error for the first component on the page which uses Styled Components. If I remove that component I get the error for the next one and so on, so I assume there's a problem with the hydration process and it's happening for every className.

I have a **_document.tsx** file which extends the Document class and has the following getInitialProps function

```
static async getInitialProps (ctx) {

    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {

        ctx.renderPage = () =>
            originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
        })

        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        
        return {
            ...initialProps,
            styles: (
                <>
                    {initialProps.styles}
                    {sheet.getStyleElement()}
                </>
            )
        }
        
    } finally {
        sheet.seal()
    }
    
}
```

My hunch is that it is something to do with this code because before I upgraded to Typescript (and had to change my _app.tsx file) I didn't get this error, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your `.babelrc` file as well, please?

Comment: There is no .babelrc file, Next doesn't add one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try installing [`babel-plugin-styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components), then add a `.babelrc` file to the root of the project with the following configuration. This ensures that no mismatches in classes generation occur during rehydration.

```json
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

From the [`babel-plugin-styled-components`'s documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#serverside-rendering):

> By adding a unique identifier to every styled component, this plugin avoids checksum mismatches due to different class generation on the client and on the server. If you do not use this plugin and try to server-side render styled-components React will complain with an HTML attribute mismatch warning during rehydration.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Do I still need to leave everything as it is in my _document.tsx file?

Comment: Yes, your `_document.tsx` looks good to me.

Comment: Just to add though, I added a .babelrc file, not Babel.config.json

Comment: Any update to swc compiler?

Comment: @decryptingfuture Looks like the Next.js team has plans to port this plugin to the SWC compiler: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30802. Until then I guess you're stuck with Babel.

Comment: Thanks, it helped to solve my problem!

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components

Comment: I read that Next.js documentation part, so the plugging part I had already tried it but it threw a syntax error: Unexpected token, since my project had typescript in it. The part that did the trick was: "presets": ["next/babel"], and not just the plugins part  like the documentation tells you to include in your .babelrc file. Thanks a lot, I do not know from  where did you pull out that answer, but you are a life saver.

Answer (score 9):

Next.js added support for Styled Components since `v12.0.1`. The only thing you need to do is modify the `next.config.js` file. It should look like the following.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // This is the property you need to add
  compiler: {
    // ssr and displayName are configured by default
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Source: [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components)

Comment: You may want to point out that this config is for the Next.js compiler (SWC), not Babel.

Comment: This did not do anything for me. :/

Comment: I wasn't using babel, but SWC. I added `_document.js` as mentioned in other stackoverflow answers, still the problem persist until I had to modify the `next.config.js` with this solution. Thanks it worked for me.