# Hot reloading for Styled Components and MDX fails

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm using `MDXRemote` from `next-mdx-remote` to load content from local .mdx files into my .tsx files.

I'm also passing components that are created by `styled-components` into the `<MDXRemote/>` component.

Here's an example:

```js
// index.tsx
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Main = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
`

const components = {
  Main
}

const Home: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MDXRemote {...props.source} components={components}/>
    </div>
  )
}

...
```

The MDX file:

```markdown
// post.mdx

<Main>

# Hello World!

</Main>
```

When I run `next dev` it renders fine the first time, with all the correct styling. But if I make a change that causes hot-reload to occur, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "sc-eCstlR hmAVQF" Client: "sc-gsTEea jglPTv"
    at div
```

I'm guessing this is because of the `styled-components` lib changing the classname on rebuild. Is there a workaround for this? Otherwise I need to constantly stop and re-run `next dev` for every change.

I've also tried with `@emotion/styled` and that doesn't have the same issue. But I would ideally like to not use `@emotion/styled` because our entire component library is using `styled-components`.

Comment: Does this help with your question: [Warning: Prop `className` did not match in Next.JS site with Styled Components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862300/1870780)?

Comment: Will give that a try @juliomalves! Thanks

Comment: Yup, that did it. My mistake, I didn't finish reading the bit on server side rendering from the styled components documentation. This blog is also helpful: https://medium.com/swlh/server-side-rendering-styled-components-with-nextjs-1db1353e915e